# Convert array of JSON objects to string in pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have one requirement in which I need to create a custom JSON from the columns returned from one PySpark dataframe. So I wrote one UDF like the below which will return a JSON in String format from UDF for each row.

Parameter "entities" are in the array of JSON format.

```
def halResponse(entities, admantx, copilot_id): 
  json_resp = "{\"analyzedContent\": {"+json.dumps(entities)+"}}"
  return json_resp
```

But in the response, I am not getting proper JSON i.e instead of proper key: value pair, I am just getting values(actual values replace with * for security purpose), not key and value.

Find the sample response:

```
  "analyzedContents": [
    {
      "entities": [
        [
          "******",
          *,
          *********,
          [
            [
              "***********",
              "***********",
              "***********",
              [
                "*****************"
              ],
              **********
            ]
          ],
          "**************"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. After fixing, I should get the below sample response

```
  "analyzedContents": [
    {
      "entities": [
        [
          "key":******",
          "key":*,
          "key":*********,
          [
            [
              "key":"***********",
              "key":"***********",
              "key":"***********",
              [
                "key":"*****************"
              ],
              "key":**********
            ]
          ],
          "key":"**************"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: try using `F.to_json` https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_json

Comment: And how that JSON can be converted to string

Comment: it is a string, no need for further conversion.

Comment: But i am getting this 'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str' when I am concatenating it in udf

Comment: could you edit your question and show the udf and the code that you used (with `F.to_json`)?

Comment: Ok i used json.dumps(entities) and it is giving me json in string format

Comment: `F.to_json` already converts to json string, no need for `json.dumps`. How did you use `F.to_json`?

Comment: "display(copilot_hal_df.withColumn('entities_as_string', F.to_json(F.col('entities'))))", I am using this in existing dataframe

Comment: Ohh... so the dataframe already has a json string column called `entities`? Does that column contain the keys?

Comment: Yes it has keys.

Comment: Then can you try `F.concat(F.lit("{\"analyzedContent\": {"), F.col("entities"), F.lit("}}"))`? no need for udf.

Comment: ok i will try and let u know 

Comment: I tried it and it gives me below error:


org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve &#39;concat(&#39;{&#34;analyzedContent&#34;: {&#39;, `entities`, &#39;}}&#39;)&#39; due to data type mismatch: input to function concat should all be the same type,

Comment: How about `F.concat(F.lit("{\"analyzedContent\": {"), F.to_json(F.col("entities")), F.lit("}}"))`?

Comment: Actually i used the the same F.json column and concate it and its working now

Comment: good, should I post that as an answer then?

Comment: Yes you can post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this without using an UDF:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'response',
    F.concat(
        F.lit("{\"analyzedContent\": {"),
        F.to_json(F.col("entities")),
        F.lit("}}")
    )
)
```